# Strange behavior of mktime() when using passing parameter created by malloc

Tags: c, date, malloc, mktime, time.h

Below I have four functions.
`first()` and `second()` initialize only the year, mon & mday of structure `tm`.
`first_p()` and `second_p` allocate memory using malloc, then assign year, mon & mday.
All functions call `mktime()` at the end.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void first()
{
    int year1 = 2020, month1 = 4, day1 = 23;
    struct tm date1 = {.tm_year = year1-1900, .tm_mon = month1-1, .tm_mday = day1};
    mktime(&date1);
    printf("%s", asctime(&date1));
}

void second()
{
    int year2 = 2021, month2 = 5, day2 = 24;
    struct tm date2 = {.tm_year = year2-1900, .tm_mon = month2-1, .tm_mday = day2};
    mktime(&date2);
    printf("%s", asctime(&date2));
}

void first_p()
{
    int year1 = 2020, month1 = 4, day1 = 23;
    struct tm *date1 = (struct tm *) malloc (sizeof(struct tm));
    date1->tm_year = year1 - 1900;
    date1->tm_mon = month1 -1;
    date1->tm_mday = day1;
    mktime(date1);
    printf("%s", asctime(date1));
}

void second_p()
{
    int year2 = 2021, month2 = 5, day2 = 24;
    struct tm *date2 = (struct tm *) malloc (sizeof(struct tm));
    date2->tm_year = year2 - 1900;
    date2->tm_mon = month2 - 1;
    date2->tm_mday = day2;
    mktime(date2);
    printf("%s", asctime(date2));
}
```

I tried different permutation when calling these functions in `main()`:

1) `first_p()` and `second_p()` show random date and time.

```
int main()
{
    first();
    second();
    first_p();
    second_p();

    return 0;
}
```

```
Thu Apr 23 00:00:00 2020
Mon May 24 00:00:00 2021
Thu Sep 30 23:09:20 66488
Wed Aug 31 14:44:48 66489
```

2) only `second_p()` shows random date and time.

```
int main()
{
    first_p();
    second_p();
    first();
    second();

    return 0;
}
```

```
Thu Apr 23 00:00:00 2020
Sun Dec  8 01:26:16 -103880
Thu Apr 23 00:00:00 2020
Mon May 24 00:00:00 2021
```

3) Only `second_p()` shows random date and time.

```
int main()
{
    first_p();
    first();
    second();
    second_p();

    return 0;
}
```

```
Thu Apr 23 00:00:00 2020
Thu Apr 23 00:00:00 2020
Mon May 24 00:00:00 2021
Thu Oct  9 04:53:52 60110
```

4) `first_p()` and `second_p()` show random date and time.

```
int main()
{
    first();
    first_p();
    second_p();
    second();

    return 0;
}
```

```
Thu Apr 23 00:00:00 2020
Sat Sep 25 12:05:36 182934
Fri Aug 26 03:41:04 182935
Mon May 24 00:00:00 2021
```

What I observe is:

- Directly initializing the structure and then passing it to mktime() anywhere has no strange behavior.
- Allocating memory using malloc, then assigning the values and later passing it to mktime() has two behaviours:

  - If mktime() is being called for the first time, then there is no strange behavior.
  - else it shows shows some random date and time. Sometimes years are negative!

Am I missing something about mktime() that's responsible for this behavior?

**Edit:**
I added `free(date1);` and `free(date2);` at the end of `first_p()` and `second_p()`. Now calling `*_p()` functions one after another doesn't display random date and time. However calling `first()` or `second()` function before them shows random date and time for the first `*_p()` function while the functions the come after it doesn't, i.e, for cases 1) , 3) and 4) listed above.

However, can't free it as I need them somewhere else (why I had to use malloc in the first place). Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Fill in all the fields of the structure. `malloc` does not do that for you; it does not set the memory to zero or otherwise initialize it for you. (Defining a structure inside a function also does not initialize it by default but, if you give initial values for some fields, the others are initialized to zero.)

Comment: the `malloc`d memory is _not_ initialized. Set it to zero, or call `calloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got quasi-random (indeterminate) values in the hours, minutes, seconds and daylight saving flag in the `malloc()` data, so you get indeterminate results back from `mktime()`.

Use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, or zero the fields yourself.

Also, consider setting the `tm_isdst` member to `-1` to let the system determine whether daylight saving or standard time was appropriate for the dates.

Comment: Thanks! Using ```calloc()``` solved the problem. However, I still don't understand why the first time ```mktime()``` is called there is no such random behavior, irrespective whether I use malloc() or calloc(), i,e in cases 3) and 4) I've mentioned.

Comment: With the local variables initialized with designated initializers, the fields not explicitly initialized are implicitly (but definitively) zeroed.  With the `malloc()` memory, you don't know what you've got — using `calloc()` effectively uses `memset()` to zero the memory, so you could do the same.  You could set the year, month, day, hour, minute, second and DST fields to zero (or other known value)  and `mktime()` is required to work.  It won't pay attention to the 'day of year' or 'day of week' fields while determining the time, but it will set them using the time information.

Comment: For the rest, undefined behaviour is undefined — anything can happen.  Sometimes, the data returned by `malloc()` could be mostly zero just because.